# Highcharts: Inconsistent linebreaks on x-axis with IE8 (exporting)

Tags: highcharts

I've got a slight issue with graph exporting in IE8.
As the title says, there seems to be some inconsistent behavior when it comes to linebreaks. As a result, the x-axis labels tend to overlap one another. This becomes more apparent when I increase the font size slightly.

Does anyone have any experience with this, or possibly any advice?

Note: Things work fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: which IE8 version u are using?

Comment: Version 8.0.7601..
Running in "normal" IE8 mode, not compatibility mode.

Comment: its working fine for me, snapshot might help us.

Comment: Alright, here's a quick snapshot (browser on the left, exported png on the right):
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1618226/img/ie8_vs_export.PNG